# Check weather in object's context or not in PHP

Tags: php, oop

In the class provided , i need to call **pre** function from both way statically and within object. But i could not do that .My class code

```
class mc {

   public $trace_back = 1;

    public static function pre() {
        if(isset($this) && isset($this->trace_back)){
            $trace_back = $this->trace_back;
        }
        else{
            $trace_back = 1;
        }
        echo $trace_back; 
    }

}
```

Now when i am calling statically

```
mc::pre(); // echo 1;
```

It echoes **1**, which is fine as expected.
But When in **object context** , like

```
function mcpre(){
    $mc = new mc();
    $mc->trace_back = 3;
    $mc->pre(); // echo 1
}
```

It again echoes 1, when 3 was expected.

In wider view my question is how can we call a function in both manners, statically as well as within object.

Also this does not work.

```
class Foo {
  function bar() {
     $static = !(isset($this) && get_class($this) == __CLASS__);
  }
}
```

Comment: Short answer : you don't. For your own sake.

Comment: why echo statement is outside function it will always print 1

Comment: oh, that's just typing mistake, i edit the question.

Comment: @Alfwed Can you make it more clear why i should i not use that. A simple link would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The static methods of a class don't have access to any non-static members, including `$this`; if you want to access the `$trace_back` in any static method, then you need declare it as static.

```
<?php
class mc {
    public static $trace_back = 1;
    public static function pre() {
        echo self::$trace_back . "<br />"; 
    }
}

mc::pre(); // echoes 1
mc::$trace_back = 2;
mc::pre(); // echoes 2
?>
```

You'll find [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) very useful.

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object
>   created, the pseudo-variable `$this` is not available inside the method
>   declared as static.
>
> Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the
>   arrow operator `->`.
>
> Calling non-static methods statically generates an `E_STRICT` level
>   warning.

Answer (score 0):

Change your function to return value from with in the function:

```
public static function pre() {
    if(isset($this) && isset($this->trace_back)){
        $trace_back = $this->trace_back;
    }
    else{
        $trace_back = 1;
    }
    return  $trace_back;
}
```

Comment: It will definitely throw an error  of **$this** not in object context.